# TS Stream Transport Over UDP from .TS files

Tags: gstreamer

I would like to transport ts stream (.ts files) over UDP.

I have used the below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=a.ts ! tsparse ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host="IP" port=port
```

But, i am getting end of the stream within fraction of seconds.

At, Receiver end i am receiving some data only.

Warning arises when i set do-timestamp=true for filesrc.

```
0:00:00.051245178  4751       0xe494a0 WARN        mpegtspacketizer mpegtspacketizer.c:1388:calculate_skew: delta - skew: 5124091:34:25.044918089 too big, reset skew
```

If i removed the do-timestamp property in filesrc, then below warning arised.

```
0:00:00.031207435  3162       0x6c1a00 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3483:gst_base_src_start_complete:<filesrc0> pad not activated yet
```

TS file is created by decode and mpegtsmux of a yuv file.

That TS file is properly working when i directly demux & decode it.

But when i stream that ts file through UDP, then this problem arises.

**How can i transport ts stream over UDP?**

Comment: hwo big is the file? maybe you are lacking something which will slow the pipe.. what about setting sync=true on udpsink.. but I think its already default..

Comment: file is about 47.7 MB. Video duration is around 12 min.

do you know what i have missed??

Comment: how is the ts file created? can you analyse it if its correct (PAT,PMT table, PCR etc..) maybe tsparse or tsdemux can dump some information about the file.. also try with GST_DEBUG=3 or 4 maybe some warnings will show..

Comment: Check the question once.