# Error when TS audio stream over UDP

Tags: gstreamer

I have a ts file which contains only audio data, i have to stream this data over UDP.

I have used the below pipeline,

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/uurmi/Desktop/GStreamer/Tasks/audio.ts ! tsdemux ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.1.139 port=7000 sync=true
```

While executing i have found below error,

```
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:audio_0041: caps = "NULL"
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: you could updated [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193678/ts-stream-transport-over-udp-from-ts-files) question while analyzing the same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is Solved by using below pipeline instead of the above pipeline

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/uurmi/Desktop/GStreamer/Tasks/audio.ts ! tsdemux ! faad ! faac ! aacparse ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.1.139 port=7000 sync=true
```

By replacing the above pipeline with this pipeline,

then i am able to transfer the Audio Data Over UDP.